# I want to change the datatype of a hive column from bigint to datetime but experiencing the below error message

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

alter table interface_detail CHANGE datetime DATE;

But I'm getting the below error... Please help.

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:67 cannot recognize input near '' '' '' in column type (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: Could you please show an example of your data and the code you are running?

Comment: I got the solution below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

alter table interface_detail CHANGE datetime datetime TIMESTAMP....

I forgot to add the column as shown above and hence throwing the error. Also, datatype DATE isn't supported so used TIMESTAMP instead.